# Gradle precompiled script plugin: External Quarkus plugin dependency not found

Tags: gradle, quarkus, gradle-kotlin-dsl, gradle-multi-project-build, kotlin-gradle-plugin

**Background**

I am currently developing a gradle multi-project with multiple quarkus microservices. In order to bundle my quarkus dependencies I use a precompile script plugin with `kotlin-dsl`. Given the configuration below, executing `quarkusBuild` works fine.

**Problem**

Executing the `quarkusDev` task for a microservice subproject fails with

`Unable to find quarkus-gradle-plugin dependency in project ':microservice'`

Do you have any idea why this happens? I have put hours into this and I still do not see why it fails. https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/12509 seems to be related, but the suggested solution did not work for me. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Edit**

I realize there might be a difference between `gradle.plugin.io.quarkus:quarkus-gradle-plugin:2.2.3.Final` and `io.quarkus:gradle-application-plugin:2.2.3.Final`, but swapping the dependencies doesnt help much.

**Configuration**

This is a minimal version of my project which allows to reproduce the error.

This minimal example can also be checked out here: https://github.com/lorenzjosten/gradle-plugin-quarkus

```
rootProject
    - buildSrc
          - src/main/kotlin
                quarkus-conventions.gradle.kts
          build.gradle.kts
          settings.gradle.kts
          gradle.properties
    - microservice
          - src/...
          build.gradle.kts
    build.gradle.kts
    settings.gradle.kts
    gradle.properties
```

rootProject/buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/quarkus-conventions.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    java
    id("io.quarkus")
}

val quarkusUniverseBomVersion: String by project

dependencies {
    implementation(enforcedPlatform("io.quarkus:quarkus-universe-bom:$quarkusUniverseBomVersion"))
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-kotlin")
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive")
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson")
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-hibernate-reactive-panache")
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-reactive-pg-client")
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-reactive-messaging-amqp")
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-arc")
    testImplementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5")
}
```

rootProject/buildSrc/build.gradle.kts

```
val quarkusPluginVersion: String by project

plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
    gradlePluginPortal()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("io.quarkus:gradle-application-plugin:${quarkusPluginVersion}")
}
```

rootProject/buildSrc/gradle.properties

```
quarkusPluginVersion=2.3.0.Final
```

rootProject/microservice/build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    id("quarkus-conventions")
}
```

rootProject/settings.gradle.kts

```
include("microservice")
```

rootProject/build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    idea
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
    gradlePluginPortal()
}

allprojects {
    apply(plugin = "idea")

    idea {
        module {
            isDownloadSources = true
            isDownloadJavadoc = true
        }
    }
}
```

rootProject/gradle.properties

```
quarkusUniverseBomVersion=2.2.3.Final
```

Answer (score 0):

The Gradle plugin likely cannot find the Java dependency:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.quarkus/quarkus-universe-bom
implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-universe-bom:2.2.3.Final")
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time and looking into it. I have to admit that I am not sure what exactly you mean by that. Is it that gradle cannot find the sources in the given repositories? Or does the io.quarkus gradle Plugin somehow struggle to work with the java sources? In the external libraries folder (i use intellij) i can see that the sources have been downloaded. I realize there maybe is difference between "gradle.plugin.io.quarkus:quarkus-gradle-plugin:2.2.3.Final" and "io.quarkus:gradle-application-plugin:2.2.3.Final", but swapping the dependencies doesnt help much.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug that should be fixed with quarkus release version 2.4.CR1

See Github issues

https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/20595
https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/20531